# Unable to setup Java home

Tags: java, maven, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm attempting to install java home and maven home in the first job and use a second job to run other tasks. The snippet belows shows where I'm able to install both maven and java home, however on the second job, I'm unable to carry out maven or java commands.

Here is the error, I'm facing:

```
/usr/bin/bash: line 147: java: command not found

Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
```

Here is the gitlab ci file

```
image: ubuntu:latest

stages:
  - setup
  - build

variables:
  MAVEN_CACHE_DIR: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=$MAVEN_CACHE_DIR"
  JAVA_HOME: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64

cache:
  paths:
  - $MAVEN_CACHE_DIR
  - /usr/lib/jvm

setup:
  stage: setup
  before_script:
    - echo "Install wget"
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y wget
    - echo "Install Java SE 17"
    - apt-get update 
    - apt-get install -y openjdk-17-jdk
    - export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
    - export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
    - source ~/.bashrc
  script:
    - echo "Install Maven"
    - apt-get update
    - mkdir -p $MAVEN_CACHE_DIR
    - wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.9.5/binaries/apache-maven-3.9.5-bin.tar.gz
    - tar -xzf apache-maven-3.9.5-bin.tar.gz
    - export MAVEN_HOME=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/apache-maven-3.9.5
    - export PATH=$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$PATH
    - source ~/.bashrc
  artifacts:
    paths:
        - ./target

build:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
    - export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
    - source ~/.bashrc
    - export MAVEN_HOME=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/apache-maven-3.9.5
    - export PATH=$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$PATH
    - source ~/.bashrc
  script:
    - java -version
    - mvn --version
  dependencies: 
    - setup
```

Comment: Do you mean `JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: The error was taken from Gitlab. Yes, I do believe it can't find JAVA_HOME in the second job

Comment: At first: Why install java on a Ubuntu Image and not using the official Maven Image, it already brings Java & Maven.

To your situation:
Have you tried to echo the current `JAVA_HOME` value? Second thing, print the content of the directory you think Java is installed to, maybe the whole path isn't correct.

Comment: I want to be able to install additional packages, which is why I went with ubuntu:latest. Within the setup stage, I tried using ```echo $JAVA_HOME```. It gave me the correct response. Within the build stage however, the command did not provide a response.